# htaccess mod rewrite rule to over-ride cakephp controller

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a site running cakephp and also a wordpress site together in the same root directory. I have the following issue. Wordpress is served requests first such that a url for the homepage will be routed through wordpress' index. Now our cakephp code includes a list of controllers that manage some special features of our site. We have a rewrite rule that looks as followed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users`. This allows urls like `www.example_site.com/users` to hit our cakephp framework instead of generating a 404 error when wordpress cannot find this page.

This rule bypasses the wordpress routing so that the request can be sent to cakephp. We are using a similar rule for each of our cakephp controllers. The issue is that we used to have a wordpress plugin that had a users page. This users page appended arguments to the url as followed `www.example_site.com/users/some_dudes_username`. Some links to these user pages are still indexed by google or in peoples bookmarks, so what is happening is the rewrite rule we wrote causes these to bypass wordpress (instead of 404ing there like it used to) and instead they hit cakephp and 404 there. I am thinking through how to make it so that any of our cakephp user controller functions are correctly redirected to (there are only a few so white-listing seems like the way to go), but any other request to the user controller for actions that will not exist like `www.example_site.com/users/some_dudes_username` would redirect to our FAQ page. I have the following white-list code which seems to work, but I cannot figure out how to correctly redirect everything else:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/users
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/admin_login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/logout  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/admin_logout
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/admin_index

# Then I need a rewrite rule to take everyone else to the FAQ page.
```

Thank you to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I totally understand your issue, but it sounds like you need a `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/users/.*$ /URI/to/faq.html [R]
```

This rule should be right after your `RewriteCond` since the conditions only apply to the rule right after them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I think I need. I think I need to do some more research to better explain myself here.